# Android Construct and Syntax Errors

Tags: java, android

I've found this example code online. It seems to do what I want, making a request to an API, I just need to customize it a bit.

However, it when I try to compile it, it gives me the same errors for three lines

```
 Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
 construct(s)
- Syntax error on token "setEntity", = 
 expected after this token
```

Maybe some one can see something I don't?

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class http {

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");


    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


 }
```

The error is thrown for the nameValuePairs.add lines, and the httppost.setEntity line

Comment: the error changes for the nameValuePairs by putting "add" in the quotes for the error

Comment: your code should be in a method. please read a java tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Ran said: you may want to pick up some basic Java programming lessons / tutorials first. Some programming-related tutorials assume that you are already familiar with that and just list a few lines of code that are not directly usable that way, because they belong inside a method.

You need to rewrite your class as follows ("myMethodName" can be any other name of your choice)

```
public class http {
   public void myMethodName() {
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

       // Execute HTTP Post Request
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   }
}
```

And then this piece of code cannot be executed as is. You need to create an instance of your class "http" and call its "myMethodName" method from an Android Activity.